# SQL JOIN error in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I have this sql string:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT TOP 1 ID, FName, FoodGroup, Calories, Protein, Carbohydrates, Fat, category.ID" &
        " FROM food where Protein<='" & txtProt.Text.ToString() & "' and FoodGroup = 4 " & "and category.ID = 1 " & "JOIN foodCategory ON food.ID = foodCategory.Food_ID" & "JOIN category ON foodCategory.Category_ID = category.ID " & "ORDER BY NEWID() "
```

What i want to do is this: I want to type the value "FName" from table "food" to an textBox where the "ID" field of table "category" is 1.

I have 3 tables. The first is table food, the second one is table category and the third one is foodCategory.
The table foodCategory has the ID's from the first 2 tables to a one-to-many relationship.
I get the following error : Incorrect syntax near JOIN.
What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query is incorrect, the JOINs have to be set within the FROM clause, not in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query

```
dim sqlQuery As String 
sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 ID, FName, FoodGroup, Calories, Protein, " & _
           "Carbohydrates, Fat, category.ID " &_
           "FROM food JOIN foodCategory ON " & _
           "food.ID = foodCategory.Food_ID JOIN category ON " & _
           "foodCategory.Category_ID = category.ID " & _
           "where Protein<='" & txtProt.Text.ToString() & "' and " & _
           "FoodGroup = 4 and category.ID = 1 " & _
           "ORDER BY NEWID() "
```

Furthermore you should have look at **Parameter** as your code is very vulnerable to **SQL injection**!

Comment: The "and" is not necessary. otherwise the code works. Thanks for the warning about sql injection too!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your concatenation:

```
... foodCategory.Food_ID" & "JOIN category ...
```

would evaluate to

```
foodCategory.Food_IDJOIN category
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN must be before the WHERE clause:

```
 " FROM food" & " JOIN foodCategory ON food.ID = foodCategory.Food_ID" & "JOIN category ON       foodCategory.Category_ID = category.ID " & " WHERE Protein<='" & txtProt.Text.ToString() & "'  and FoodGroup = 4 " & "and category.ID = 1 " & " ORDER BY NEWID() ";
```